# java remove regular and special characters between two strings in a file

Tags: java, string

I have a file that has has a section something like:

```
some phrase taxlabels gjasfg%$*!#%$97 dimensions more
```

I want to remove everything between taxlabels and dimensions so that it reads:

```
some phrase more
```

I tried:

```
fw.write(br.readLine().replaceAll("taxlabels.*?dimensions", "");
```

but nothing happens to the file. If I replace just one word e.g. "taxlabels" it works fine so I know its this line that is the problem. I think the problem is that `.*?` doesn't work for special characters, but I can't work out how to account for both regular and special characters. Any advice?

Comment: I checked, the replace all is working fine. Is this code compiling?  Are you not missing an ending brace?

Comment: Have you made sure that its the regular expression that is failing and not some IO problem?

Comment: This is working in simple java program.. I think there might be problem with your program.

Comment: My program compiles fine and I can run it with no IO errors. The program is designed to make several other changes to the file and they are carried out with no problems.

Comment: To clarify, I have tested and I can replace "taxlabels" on its own, I can replace "dimensions" on it's own, and I can replace between "some" and "taxlabels" but it will not replace what is between "taxlabels" and "dimensions".